# Primes and Squares

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Place a different prime or square number on each of the fifteen disks below so that the number in any disk that lies on two others is the sum of the numbers in those disks. Do so in such a way that the number on the apex is as small as possible.

[image]

Comment: is this something you composed yourself?

Comment: @KateGregory: A variation on an old theme.

Comment: Zero (as a square) allowed?

Comment: @z100 You could not use a zero, since $x + 0 = x$, and therefore  you'd have to have two $x$'es in your grid; that is disallowed. See https://imgur.com/a/gPWWkaN for explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A much lower upper bound, which I'm fairly sure is optimal (assuming 0 is disallowed).

> ```
>               1669 
>            576 || 1093 
>        383 || 193 || 900 
>     347 ||  36 || 157 || 743 
>  324 || 23 ||  13 || 144 || 599
> ```

Comment: Algorithm used extening the order? E.G.: 1st order:
1 ;

2nd order:
 3 (1 2)  ;

3rd order:
  16  (3 13) (1 2 11) ; or   16 (13 3) (12 1 2) ;

Comment: @z100 I'm afraid I'm not sure what you're asking - could you clarify?

Comment: My own (extremely shameful, dirty, brute-force) code confirms this answer is optimal. I can also provide the smallest apex value for a 4-level tree, which is 23.

Comment: @benj2240: 23? How?

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos Oh! You're right, 23 isn't possible. I didn't notice that I had a duplicated 3... Dirty code leads to dirty bugs. Let me correct myself: The smallest apex value for a 4-level tree is 59.

Comment: @benj2240: Yes, 59 is the lowest my students have achieved.

Answer (score 5):

Alright, I’ve definitely got an upper bound here.

> [image]

In text:

> ```
>                   390625 
>              140625 || 250000 
>          50625 || 90000 || 160000 
>      18225 || 32400 || 57600 || 102400 
>  6561 || 11664 || 20736 || 36864 || 65536
> ```

However,

> this uses all square numbers, and is far from optimal. I’ll have to see if I can reduce it by using primes.